# Can I use my mid-2010 imac as a display for my PC with HDMI input?

Tags: imac, pc

Can I use my 27" 2010 imac with mini display as a monitor with my new PC that has an HDMI and USB-C inputs? I bought a mini display to HDMI cable off Amazon and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has just such a page in its knowledgebase on [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592#requirements).

But the one thing they do not mention is if it works with Windows (or other) PCs. It would make sense that it should/could work but I have no experience in doing so. Perhaps that article will help. perhaps others who have tried this will know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an active HDMI to Mini DisplayPort adapter that will convert the signal, a simple cable will not work. They're quite expensive. See here: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/ins-outs-imacs-target-display-mode/